# Button to change text on background

Tags: android

Hello all im fairly new to this and may need some assistance, this is very simple,

what do i need to add to this code

```
   public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
               tx.setText("Hello");
           }
    });
    }
    }
```

to make it so when the button is pressed it changes the text view to a random string in my strings.xml list
if i labelled the strings, string1 ,string2, etc.

Comment: Can you brief out what you exactly want to achieve? I am not able to get your requirements.

Comment: to make an app the whenever the button is pushed it gives a random peace of text in the middle of the screen and when you push it again it gives you another random text and so forth and so forth

Comment: Hi, instead of string1, string2, etc. Why not just use an array resource? Then you can simply play with the index.

Comment: yeh i could do that how would i put that into the code?

Comment: ok now i have edited my code how do i make it so when you push the button again after hello it says something else ?

Comment: Can anyone solve my dilema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create the `string-array` and use it as below:

Try out this way:

> ```
> Resources res = this.getResources();
>   final String[] capital = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);
>   Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
>    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>         if(count<capital.length-1)
>         tv2.setText(capital[count]);
>         count++;
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: where do i put my text from the strings ?

Comment: Put your strings in `strings.xml` file as `string-array` and assign that array in `final String[] capital = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        String[] myStrings;
        int currentText;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        currentText = 0;
        setListeners();

        myStrings = new String [200];
        myStrings[0] = "String1";
        myStrings[1] = "String2";
    }


    public void changeText(){
        tv2.setText(myStrings[currentText[);
        currentText++;

    }

    public void setListeners(){
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        changeText();

                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I did not test this code. I hope this helps you!

Comment: im getting erros for tv2, b, OnTouchListener, MotionEvent keep saying tv2 cannot be resolved create local variable etc